# If you modify code in the Rails console will that affect a server running in parallel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible to run "rails console" in one shell and then "rails server" in another and then have code changes in the console permeate to the running application? Presumably this isn't possible, but I'd just like to check if there is a way.

Edit: Both are running in the same environment. And by code changes I mean changes to class definitions (e.g. rewriting a method on the Post model).

Comment: What do you mean by "code changes"? You can use console to update, insert or delete data in the database. That's all and it WILL affect the running application.

Comment: I say code to distinguish it with data. I.e. if I refine a method on my Post class will that permeate to the version of Rails running on console.

Comment: No, it will not. Mario's answer is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you modify any data, that will indeed permeate.  However modifications to methods done on the fly by opening classes and "monkey-patching" them will not affect your running application - unless your modified method modifies data.

However, it is always advisable to run the console in a different environment with different data to avoid harming a running application.

Comment: To elaborate, monkeypatched code on the console app won't affect the server app because you're running different instances, and only the server app is serving live traffic. Data changes (side effects) will permeate because by default your console and server app will be using shared resources like the same DB. Note that the console code change limitation doesn't always hold for other stacks. For example in Elixir, you can connect your console to a running node that's serving traffic, reload a module, and then the changes DO affect the code running on that server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing data in your console IN THE SAME ENVIRONMENT then it will be changed in the browser.