# How to use Rails Console after I run "rails server"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating a rails application, and really like to use the rails console to help myself understand what's happening when I create forms and invoke models.

My method is as follows:

```
rails s
```

followed by creating a new user or post, etc, then

```
ctrl + c
rails console
```

and then I can look at how the objects are being saved in the database and what is or is not working.

**My Question:**

Is there a way to access and use the rails console after I run "rails s"?

Comment: I think @vinchenzio's is the answer you are looking for! You don't have to quit the server in order to use the console. Just open another terminal! But you should also consider getting yourself familiar with a debugger, like byebug or pry. It will be super useful!

Comment: possible duplicate of [If you modify code in the Rails console will that affect a server running in parallel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804941/if-you-modify-code-in-the-rails-console-will-that-affect-a-server-running-in-par)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you run "rails s" open a new tab in the terminal (make sure that it is the same directory) and run rails console. The database it will be referring to in the console is the one being run by rails s.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! I'll checkmark your answer once the time limit expires

Comment: No problem, happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could try use a ruby debugger as [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) or [pry-debug](https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger)

add on your gemfile this line (on developer group)

```
gem byebug
```

and then on your code you will be able to add breackpoint like this.

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  def new
    byebug
    @person = Person.new
  end
```

end

More information [HERE](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-byebug-gem)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, you could also run the [rails server in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334403/how-to-start-rails-server-in-background) (check this link for different ways of doing so depending on what you are looking for) if you'd prefer to not have multiple terminal tabs open.